# PHP strtolower only domain

Tags: php, regex, substr

I need to `strtolower` URL, but only part till `/` after `mysite.co`

`URLS` could be starts with `http://www` `www` `https` or without any.

Also domain zone could be any, and `URL` could be with subdomains.

I cant get how to use `substr` in that case, maybe here need `regexp` but im not very good with it.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you give some examples (what you have and what you want it to be)? I have problems understanding what exactly you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `substr` in conjunction with `strpos`.
Somehow like this:

```
$url = 'http://www.MySite.co/Index.php';
if ($i = strpos($url, '/', strpos($url, '//')+2))
    $url = strtolower(substr($url, 0, $i)). substr($url, $i);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `parse-url`:

```
<?php
$url = 'http://username:password@hostname/path?arg=value#anchor';

print_r(parse_url($url));

echo parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH);
?>
```

Result

```
Array
(
    [scheme] => http
    [host] => hostname
    [user] => username
    [pass] => password
    [path] => /path
    [query] => arg=value
    [fragment] => anchor
)
/path
```

Comment: Exactly what I was going to say - except maybe with a strtolower for the host section - and the second example on the docs - where it parses a real host, not a relative.